# sql calculate present students in class on multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sqlite

in `barcodes` table i have two column witch they are `enter`, `exit` like with student attendance record,

in this table when student entered to class, i add new row in table and `enter` value is `1` and `exit` is `0` like with login

after exiting from classroom i check latest row of this student and if `enter` is `1` then i add new row in table with `1` value for `exit` like with logout

now i want to calculate counting all students witch `enter` column is `1` and `exit` value is `0` to get all present students in class

## SAMPLE DATA:

in this [DB-FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ruK2VrWzu7BqKbGNcKCbVk/7) i have sample data and into that i have `2` present student that `session_id` of them is `1`, they are `123451`,`123452` students, but my sql command as second part is incorrect and that return one present student:

```
(
 select count(*) 
 from barcodes b 
 where b.session_id = s.id
 group by session_id, barcode 
 having sum(exit) = 0

) as present
```

for example:

```
select s.id, s.session_name, s.session_type, s.date_time,
   (
     select count(*) 
        from barcodes b where b.session_id = s.id
    ) as barcode_count ,
    (
     select count(*) 
     from barcodes b 
     where b.session_id = s.id
     group by session_id, barcode 
     having sum(exit) = 0

    ) as present

from sessions s;
```

Comment: Is there any good reason to insert a new row on exit, istead of updating the existing row and `set exit = 1`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel no unfortunately i can't, because of other developers in server side needs to have this structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get what you want to do right, you can add another, outer aggregation.

```
...
(SELECT sum(x.count)
        FROM (SELECT count(*) count
                     FROM barcodes b
                     WHERE b.session_id = s.id
                     GROUP BY b.session_id,
                              b.barcode
                     HAVING sum(b.enter) <> 0
                            AND sum(b.exit) = 0) x) present
...
```

But I think there's a much simpler way to get what you want by just taking the sum of `enter` minus `exit` for the session. Since any row with `exit = 1` also comes with `enter = 1`, we need to double the `exit` before subtraction though.

```
...
(SELECT sum(b.enter - 2 * b.exit)
        FROM barcodes b
        WHERE b.session_id = s.id) present
...
```

Comment: second part is not correct and i get wrong result, but first part seems correct

Answer (score 1):

If you can trust the data, something like this could work:

```
select 
  s.id,
  s.session_name,
  s.session_type,
  s.date_time,
  count(*) as barcode_count,
  sum(exit = 0) - sum(exit = 1) as present
from sessions s
left join barcodes b on b.session_id = s.id
group by s.id, s.session_name, s.session_type, s.date_time
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eHmJJMpQr83tGv9F7L8ZbB/0)

You can read `sum(exit = 0) - sum(exit = 1)` as `(number of entries) - (number of exits)`. If 4 students entered a class and 2 left the class, I would expect 2 students (4 - 2) to be still in the class.

Comment: thanks, your command is not correct sir, because i have 2 present in result and after changing `exit` of `123452` to `1` i should to get 1 present for `class_a` session name, but i get zero, and this incorrect

Comment: @DolDurma I asked you, why don't you just update `exit` from 0 to 1. You wrote, you can't do that. So why are you doing that now? If you instead insert a new row for exit, it works as expected: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fPnNyan6oFe2sP6CfUZmdU/0